# Sortable как запретить перетаскивание в ненужные списки?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, sortable

Есть таблица ввиде КАБАН (см. фото) сортировка через Sortable
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть мини-карточки, которые перетаскиваются по статусам.

HTML этих столбцов примерно такой:

```
<ul class="status-ul status-id-1" data-id-status='1'>
  <div class="title_status_suppilo">название статуса</div>
  <li class="card">
     <div class="drag-item-suppilo-status">c</div>
     <ul class="action">
       <li class="card">удалить</li>
       <li class="card">редактировать</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

js

```
$( ".status-id-1, status-id-2" ).sortable({
                                        connectWith: ".status-ul",
                                        cancel: ".title_status_suppilo",
                                        items: 'li', // Указывает какие элементы в группе могут быть отсортированы. 
                                        handle: '.drag-item-suppilo-status', //Указывает элемент, при щелчке на который начнется перетаскивание. 
                                        helper:'original', // Устанавливает вид элемента помощника  original или clone
                                        opacity:1, // прозрачность перетаскиваемого элемента
                                        cursor: 'n-resize', // вид курсора при нажатии
                                        revert: 'true', // эффект вставляния перетаскиваемого элемента
                                        placeholder:"ui-state-highlight",
                                        start: function (){
                                            ///...
                                        },
                                        beforeStop: function (event, ui){
                                            ///...
                                        } 

                                    }).disableSelection();
```

Проблема в том-что когда перетаскиваемый элемент  случайно  попадает на список , то если его там отпустить он туда и попадет, а нужно чтобы только в рамках списков .

**Как запретить перетаскивание в ненужные списки?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

решил обычным добавлением класса в сортируемый элемент

```
items: 'li.kaban-block',
```